# C# оптимизировать помощник изучения слов

Tags: c#, алгоритм, winforms

Суть задания была в том, чтобы сделать программу, которая помогает выучить дни недели на англ. Я, конечно, сделал это, но вот способ которым я решил это сделать меня вообще не устраивает, в голову ничего умнее не шло и решил пойти колхозным путём. В интерфейсе установлены 7 radioButton которые подписаны русскими днями недели и в итоге я сравниваю элементы массива с этими radioButton. Подскажите пожалуйста, как по человечески это можно было сделать, с расчётом на то что слов может быть не только 7, а больше, допустим ~30-40. Спасибо за внимание!

Класс формы:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = AppLogic.NewWord();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(AppLogic.CurrentWord == default)
                MessageBox.Show("Нажмите кнопку \"Новое слово\" для старта", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);
            else if (radioButton1.Checked && AppLogic.CurrentWord == AppLogic.EngWords[1])
                SendMsg();
            else if (radioButton2.Checked && AppLogic.CurrentWord == AppLogic.EngWords[2])
                SendMsg();
            else if(radioButton3.Checked && AppLogic.CurrentWord == AppLogic.EngWords[3])
                SendMsg();
            else if (radioButton4.Checked && AppLogic.CurrentWord == AppLogic.EngWords[4])
                SendMsg();
            else if (radioButton5.Checked && AppLogic.CurrentWord == AppLogic.EngWords[5])
                SendMsg();
            else if (radioButton6.Checked && AppLogic.CurrentWord == AppLogic.EngWords[6])
                SendMsg();
            else if (radioButton7.Checked && AppLogic.CurrentWord == AppLogic.EngWords[0])
                SendMsg();
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Неверно. Попробуйте ещё!", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);

            void SendMsg()
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Правильный ответ!", "Ответ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);
                label1.Text = AppLogic.NewWord();
            }
        }
```

Класс AppLogic:

```
public static class AppLogic
    {
        public static string[] EngWords =
        {
            "Sunday",
            "Monday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday",
            "Saturday"
        };

        static Random rnd = new Random();

        public static string CurrentWord = default;

        public static string NewWord()
        {
            return CurrentWord = EngWords[rnd.Next(0, EngWords.Length)];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Элементы руками создаете или кодом? Я бы на вашем месте сделал бы автоматическую генерацию этих `radioButton`, где в `Tag` писал бы значение из `EngWords`. Тогда вся ваша портянка бы была такой `var result = контролы.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Checked )?.Tag == AppLogic.CurrentWord;`.

Comment: В данном случае кодом. Спасибо за помощь! Я понял о чём вы!